# minimax algorithm tic-tac-toe

Tags: ruby, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I am stuck on implementing the minimax algorithm for a tic tac toe game. I keep getting the same error every time (undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)) but can't seem to fix it.

My implementation is as follows:

```rb
def minimax(current_board, current_player)
  if user_won?(current_board)
    return -10
  elsif computer_won?(current_board)
    return 10
  elsif tie?(current_board)
    return 0
  end

  available_squares = empty_squares(current_board)
  moves = []

  available_squares.each do |available_square|
    move = {}
    current_board[available_square] = COMPUTER_MARKER if current_player == 'computer'
    current_board[available_square] = PLAYER_MARKER if current_player == 'player'
    score = minimax(current_board, alternate_player(current_player))
    current_board[available_square] = INITIAL_MARKER
    move[available_square] = score
    moves.push(move)
  end

  best_move = nil
  best_score = current_player == 'computer' ? -Float::INFINITY : Float:: INFINITY

  if current_player == 'computer'
    for hsh in moves
      hsh.each do |move, score|
        if score > best_score
          best_move = move
          best_score = score
        end
      end
    end
  else
    for hsh in moves 
      hsh.each do |move, score|
        if score < best_score
          best_move = move
          best_score = score
        end
      end
    end
  end
  best_move
end
```

I have been stuck on this for days so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the rest of my code: https://github.com/YBirader/launch_school/blob/master/RB101/lesson_6/ttt.rb

Comment: It looks like score is being defined inside a loop, available_squares.each - so if available_squares is empty, that code will never be run, and score will not be defined. That would cause this error.

Comment: score is only being used within the block. It is being added to the move hash, which is then destructively appended to the moves array so that shouldn't be the problem. I've added the rest of my code if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `score` has to be defined outside of the loop. Then the line

```
if score > best_score
```

will work.

Comment: I've tried that but it still doesn't work. I get the same error. Also, the each block is accessing the score key of the hash elements of moves, so I don't need to define score prior to the for loop.

Comment: To test if this is the problem, try adding ‘score = 0’ before ‘available_squares.each’.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been through and debugged this.

It turns out that the minimax method is occasionally returning nil, which is then pushed into the hash of moves on line 94, as it can't compare nil to any number with `>` or `<` this throws an error, and we can't proceed.

You just need to add a fallback to 0 when the result is nil, change line 91 to this:

```
minimax(current_board, alternate_player(current_player)) || 0
```

You also don't need to define `score` outside of the loop, as that variable is only used to add it to the hash on line 94. What I'd missed earlier is that score is defined again in the `each` loop.

Comment: But this is a bug if minimax returns 0?

Comment: yep. Although it gets rid of the error, the minimax function doesn't work anymore i.e. the logic is now wrong.