# Anyone fancy a challenge? minimax tic-tac-toe

Tags: ruby, recursion, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I am stuck on implementing the minimax algorithm for a tic tac toe game. I keep getting the same error every time (undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)) but me and various people I have now asked, can't seem to fix it.

My minimax implementation is as follows:

```rb
def minimax(current_board, current_player)
  if user_won?(current_board)
    return -10
  elsif computer_won?(current_board)
    return 10
  elsif tie?(current_board)
    return 0
  end

  available_squares = empty_squares(current_board)
  moves = []
  score = nil

  available_squares.each do |available_square|
    move = {}
    current_board[available_square] = COMPUTER_MARKER if current_player == 'computer'
    current_board[available_square] = PLAYER_MARKER if current_player == 'player'
    score = minimax(current_board, alternate_player(current_player))
    current_board[available_square] = INITIAL_MARKER
    move[available_square] = score
    moves.push(move)
  end

  best_move = nil
  best_score = current_player == 'computer' ? -Float::INFINITY : Float:: INFINITY

  if current_player == 'computer'
    moves.each do |hsh|
      hsh.each do |move, score|
        if score > best_score
          best_move = move
          best_score = score
        end
      end
    end
  else
    moves.each do |hsh| 
      hsh.each do |move, score|
        if score < best_score
          best_move = move
          best_score = score
        end
      end
    end
  end
  best_move
end
```

When minimax is called recursively, it sometimes returns `nil`, which is then appended to the `move` hash, where `move` is then appended to the `moves` array. This causes the `<` operator to raise the said exception. I don't know why `nil` is being returned.

I can only assume my logic is flawed. Maybe my board is not being correctly reset after trying possible board states but honestly, I don't know how to proceed. I have tried multiple implementations and always get the same error.

I have been stuck on this for over a week and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [minimax algorithm tic-tac-toe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054060/minimax-algorithm-tic-tac-toe)

Comment: Nope :(. Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: _"I don't know why nil is being returned"_ – when `moves` is empty, i.e. `[]`, `best_move` stays `nil` which then becomes the return value.

Comment: I don't understand how `minimax` works, but if you need a numeric value, you could change the method's last line to `best_move || 0` to provide a default value (change `0` to whatever makes sense)

Comment: That is ok @Stefan. I dont know Ruby but MiniMax and try to solve the problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the problem. In my `if tie?(current_board)` condition, `tie?` should take the argument `available_squares` instead. This stops an exception being raised.

Also, as @Stefan pointed out (credit to him), putting a default value ensures the correct value is output and would be written as:

```rb
score = minimax(current_board, alternate_player(current_player)) || 0
```

This solves it.

Answer (score 0):

The loop `available_squares.each` has to be followed by `return 0` ifc there where no moves anymore.

Comment: But isn't that taken care of in my terminal condition, where I have written: `if tie?(board) return 0`